# Magento 2 URL rewrite Issue : URL key already exists for specified store

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am facing this issue while saving a product programmatically on Magento 2.2.5

In any module, if I do `$product->save();` OR `$this->productRepository->save($product);` inside a loop for multiple products. I get:

*PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'the-lipstick.html-1' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID' in /home/dev3/www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228*

The error is similar to the one described here : https://www.human-element.com/url-key-specified-store-already-exists-magento-2/

Products save fine with admin area login.

Any suggested fixes so far including the ones modifying the core files (DBStorage.php) do not work on 2.2.5.

What I tried so far:
1. Fix from https://www.human-element.com/url-key-specified-store-already-exists-magento-2/
2. Fix from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210359/magento-2-product-url-rewrite-issue

Please suggest a solution/fix for M 2.2.5

Comment: We've found that the `url_key` containing an uppercase character when it was initially saved might be causing this. Magento shows the `url_key` in all lowercase, but the database has uppercase characters. Magento then thinks that the rewrite doesn't exist and tries adding it again with different casing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Fix : 
In di.xml -

`<preference for="Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage" type="MyCompany\FixUrls\Model\ProductUrlFix" />`

In ProductFixUrl write these two functions :

```
protected function doReplace(array $urls){

    $this->deleteOld($urls);
        $data = [];
        $storeId_requestPaths = [];

        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $storeId = $url->getStoreId();
            $requestPath = $url->getRequestPath();
            // Skip if is exist in the database
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM url_rewrite where store_id = $storeId and request_path = '$requestPath'";
            $exists = $this->connection->fetchOne($sql);

            if ($exists) {
                continue;
            }

            $storeId_requestPaths[] = $storeId . '-' . $requestPath;
            $data[] = $url->toArray();
        }
        try {

            $n = count($storeId_requestPaths);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
                for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
                    if ($storeId_requestPaths[$i] == $storeId_requestPaths[$j]) {
                        unset($data[$j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            parent::insertMultiple($data);

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
            /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[] $urlConflicted */
            $urlConflicted = [];
            foreach ($urls as $url) {
                $urlFound = parent::doFindOneByData(
                    [
                        UrlRewriteData::REQUEST_PATH => $url->getRequestPath(),
                        UrlRewriteData::STORE_ID => $url->getStoreId(),
                    ]
                );
                if (isset($urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID])) {
                    $urlConflicted[$urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID]] = $url->toArray();
                }
            }
            if ($urlConflicted) {
                throw new \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Exception\UrlAlreadyExistsException(
                    __('URL key for specified store already exists.'),
                    $e,
                    $e->getCode(),
                    $urlConflicted
                );
            } else {
                throw $e->getPrevious() ?: $e;
            }
        }

        return $urls;
    }

    /**
     * @param UrlRewrite[] $urls
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleteOld(array $urls)
    {
        $oldUrlsSelect = $this->connection->select();
        $oldUrlsSelect->from(
            $this->resource->getTableName(self::TABLE_NAME)
        );
        /** @var UrlRewrite $url */
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $oldUrlsSelect->orWhere(
                $this->connection->quoteIdentifier(
                    UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE
                ) . ' = ?',
                $url->getEntityType()
            );
            $oldUrlsSelect->where(
                $this->connection->quoteIdentifier(
                    UrlRewrite::ENTITY_ID
                ) . ' = ?',
                $url->getEntityId()
            );
            $oldUrlsSelect->where(
                $this->connection->quoteIdentifier(
                    UrlRewrite::STORE_ID
                ) . ' = ?',
                $url->getStoreId()
            );
        }

        // prevent query locking in a case when nothing to delete
        $checkOldUrlsSelect = clone $oldUrlsSelect;
        $checkOldUrlsSelect->reset(Select::COLUMNS);
        $checkOldUrlsSelect->columns('count(*)');
        $hasOldUrls = (bool) $this->connection->fetchOne($checkOldUrlsSelect);

        if ($hasOldUrls) {
            $this->connection->query(
                $oldUrlsSelect->deleteFromSelect(
                    $this->resource->getTableName(self::TABLE_NAME)
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have apply this solution and category save error fixed. But new updated category url key not updated in front any idea then please update here?

Answer (score 0):

After a migration and a week digging into the problem the only thing that worked for me was https://www.safemage.com/url-optimization-after-migration-magento-2.html

I had to downgrade to 2.2.7 to use it. It says it works on 2.3 but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

After looking on internet for days i can't find exact solution of this.
Then i found if we change the URLKEY of the category it will not show this error so i have done this.

```
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath())
            ->setParentId($parentId)
            ->setName('test1')
            ->setIsActive(true)
            ->setUrlKey(rand(1,1000000000));

        $category->save();
```

I use random function to add category in database with random no using  ***->setUrlKey(rand(1,1000000000));*** you can add any thing in this like duplicate category name with some random no etc.
and errors gone if it helps you give an UP. thanks

Comment: Hi Ghulam.M, where did you make this change? I am getting a similar error when saving assigning products to categories in the category page and I believe this may be the answer.

Unique constraint violation found {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException(code: 0): Unique constraint violation found at /chroot/home/a60ed167/soupandsaladbars.com/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php:121, Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DuplicateException(code: 1062): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Comment: This is the exact error: https://techutils.in/blog/tag/serializer/

 There is an integrity constraint violation, followed by this exception:
Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo::removeStorePath() must be of the type string, array given, called in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 167

Comment: Hi @ComputerGiant i did this a while ago while creating a category ... for your error Iwould recommend you to post a question on https://magento.stackexchange.com/